# Gitea webhook trigger woodpecker ci on review request

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, gitea

I have a self hosted gitea instance as well as a self hosted woodpecker server with agent. I now want to know if it's possible, to use the webhook, which is already created by woodpecker itself, to trigger a workflow if a review for a defined user was requested.

my current .woodpecker.yml looks like this:

```yaml
name: test

on:
  webhook:
    events:
      - pull_request_review_request

steps:
  test:
    image: git.xxx.com/godot-runner:latest
    commands:
      - ls -al
      - echo $(pwd)
```

I first tried it with a manual trigger and without the event and that worked just fine. After I added the webbhook event it didn't. Is it even possible to trigger the workflow with requesting a review?